# Simulate click in web.whatsapp.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

My mission is export my whatsapp contacts with profile picrures.

So I decided to make a chrome extension for this purpose.

And Here to collect phone of each I have to click them. And each time go back to contact list I guess. The button I got a problem to click on by javascript code is

[I need to click on this button by code and get full contact list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL6Yo.png)

I can find this elem by query like

```
$('.menu-horizontal span .menu-horizontal-item:nth-child(2)')
```

But when I tried to click on this element - nothing happens

```
$('.menu-horizontal span .menu-horizontal-item:nth-child(2)').click()
```

Any ideas... please!!!!. I just need to open contacts panel each time!!

I have added and used jquery but It's ok to use vanilla JavaScript

Comment: What is the exact problem click doesn't work or you can't get list?

Comment: Try using `.eq(#)`, or try adding `[#]` after the selector.

Comment: Click doesn't work. On click contacts list should appear, but nothing happens until I do it manually with my hand and mouse

Comment: Try .trigger('click')

Comment: .trigger('click') isno working!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using simulating click function in my extension - https://gist.github.com/davojta/3647dfbf006bec75f6ef7e3f8d2f3e70

Comment: Forgive I am a newbie. I included your script in popup.html. Then from content.js I am trying to call like below
     `self.simClick(clip_icon);` 
Where self is this for content.js and clip_icon is jQuerySelector for icon where  I want to click. I am getting error that `self.simClick is not a function`

Comment: Not working any more

Comment: Do you have any idea how to achieve this in 2024?